# Unable to update anything using apt " Temporary failure resolving"

Tags: networking, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Found many posts on this subject where its my /etc/resolv.conf.   I tried all the various nameserver settings.  -- IE:  nameserver 8.8.8.8,  127.0.0.1, default,  nameserver from wsl. But all result in error.  I even tried different distro's all the same,  guessing there's a setting on windows that's blocking.
'''
sudo apt update
[sudo]

```
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary" failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary" failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary" failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary" failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
'''
```

Comment: I gave up,  I just downloaded docker desktop and built my own container.  This allowed me to install everything I needed.

Comment: Its not related to /etc/resolv.conf -- but HyperV -- I tried the workarounds using bridges but still didn't work for me.